# python convert string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, date

i have a loop where i try to process set of data where one action is to convert ordinary string to datetime. everything works fine except sometimes happend a weird thing ... here is what i know

- there are exactly the same parameters entering the function always
- those parameters are the same type always
- first time i run it, it always get trought
- when it gets to second element in the loop in appx 80% throw and value error (time data did not match format)
- but after i run it again, everything is ok, and it gets stuck on next emelement ...

because my function is pretty big and there are many things happing i decide to provide you with some saple code whitch i wrote right here, just for clarification:

```
data = ['January 20 1999', 'March 4 2010', 'June 11 1819']
dformat = '%B %d %Y'

for item in data:
    out = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, dformat)
    print out
```

although this clearly works in my program it doesnt ... i have try everything i have came up with but havent succeeded yet therefore i would be glad with any idea you provide thanks

btw: the error i always get looks like this

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=March 4 2010  fmt=%B %d %Y
```

Comment: Consider posting the code that doesn't work instead of some code that does.  This will help finding the bug in the broken code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code supplied (you can see it in action [here](http://codepad.org/zVzHUhkV). We'd need a different sample that actually causes the error you describe.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: He did. He points out that although the code works, it also does not work in another context. Hence, the problem is in the context.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: I would not have figured that one out with the information given, but you obviously did :)

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I've lived in many countries, and implemented several calendaring systems. I know *way* to much about date issues. And don't get me started on time zones. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably have a different locale set up. %B is March in locales that use English, but in other locales it will fail.

For example:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.utf8')
'sv_SE.utf8'
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> data = ['January 20 1999', 'March 4 2010', 'June 11 1819']
>>> for item in data:
...     print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%B %d %Y')
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'January 20 1999' does not match format '%B %d %Y'
```

Here you see that even though the format *does* match, it claims it doesn't. And that's because the month names doesn't match. Change it to Swedish locale names, and it works again:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'sv_SE.utf8')
'sv_SE.utf8'
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> data = ['Januari 20 1999', 'Mars 4 2010', 'Juni 11 1819']
>>> for item in data:
...     print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%B %d %Y')
... 
1999-01-20 00:00:00
2010-03-04 00:00:00
1819-06-11 00:00:00
```

(Note that the above locale 'sv_SE.utf8' might not work for you, because you have to have that specific locale installed. To see which ones that are installed on a Unix machine, run this command from the command line:

```
$ locale -a
C
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
sv_FI.utf8
sv_SE.utf8
```

)

Comment: thanks i finally figured it out with your help, i didnt realise that as my loop continues it might operates with different languages and this might be the reason why it gots down every time it reached next element in loop ..., maybe im wrong, its just a thought. Anyway i really appreciate your help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty weird though... In the same run locale usually doesn't change. However, if your program keeps doing this, you might want to call 'setlocale' everytime the code enters into the loop (ugly solution, I know).