# Python - Convert Month Name to Integer

Tags: python, datetime

How can I convert 'Jan' to an integer using Datetime? When I try strptime, I get an error `time data 'Jan' does not match format '%m'`

Comment: Note that `strptime` is affected by your locale setting

Comment: `%m` is month as number. I think  you want `%b`. see: http://strftime.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [python convert string to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617267/python-convert-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have an abbreviated month name, so use `%b`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Jan', '%b')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('Aug', '%b')
datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('Jan 15 2015', '%b %d %Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 15, 0, 0)
```

`%m` is for a *numeric* month.

However, if all you wanted to do was map an abbreviated month to a number, just use a dictionary. You can build one from `calendar.month_abbr`:

```
import calendar
abbr_to_num = {name: num for num, name in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if num}
```

Demo:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> abbr_to_num = {name: num for num, name in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr) if num}
>>> abbr_to_num['Jan']
1
>>> abbr_to_num['Aug']
8
```

Comment: I get `1900-01-01 00:00:00` out of that

Comment: @huhhhhbhb: yes, what did you expect? If you don't include a year or day, the rest of the values fall back to defaults.

Comment: True, I really just wanted to get a single digit corresponding to the month number

Comment: @huhhhhbhb To get a month number from datetime instance use `datetime.strptime('Feb', '%b').month` which gives `2`.

Comment: is it more efficient to create and use a dict to map full month names (%B) to month numbers (%m)? The input I'm working with is formatted like such: `'Month ##, ####'`

Comment: @Anthony: then you have more than just a full month name and using `datetime.strptime()` makes sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have error when executing this code `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`

Comment: @LexaVey: Nowhere in my code am I using `datetime.datetime` (don't confuse the REPL echoing output of expressions with the expressions themselves). If you used `from datetime import datetime` and then are using `datetime.datetime` somewhere in your code, you simply need to remove the leading `datetime.`. Don't confuse the _module_ with the _class defined in the module_.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff-
Did you try `%b`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Sure, it came to me in a review queue and that is a standard message for when further info is requested in an answer. If you edit it to say - e.g. - "you need to use %b", then it likely wouldn't be flagged for review.

Comment: Oooh I see. Didn't realize that was a standardized message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward enough that you could consider just using a dictionary, then you have fewer dependencies anyway.

```
months = dict(Jan=1, Feb=2, Mar=3, ...)
print(months['Jan'])
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from calendar import month_abbr
month = "Jun"
for k, v in enumerate(month_abbr):
    if v == month:
        month = k
        break
print(month)

6
```

You will get the number of month 6